# Mapnik: Cannot get markers to overlap

Tags: mapnik

I'm using the Natural Earth shapefile to generate maps of ethnographic data. For every location where I have evidence of (for example) whether men or women had the job of brewing beer, I want to show a coloured marker.

My problem is that Mapnik insists on not letting the dots overlap, or even touch. This obscures a lot of the data, since many of the locations are very close to each other.

I've tried creating the markers this way:

```py
ps = mapnik.PointSymbolizer()
ps.file = svgfile
ps.allow_overlap = True
ps.ignore_placement = True
```

and like this:

```py
ps = mapnik.MarkersSymbolizer()
ps.file = svgfile
ps.allow_overlap = True
ps.ignore_placement = True
ps.spacing = 1
ps.placement = 'point'
ps.multi_policy = 'each'
```

but nothing seems to have any effect. I've tried adding and removing these properties in all possible combinations, to no effect.

For each type of marker I build a layer, style, rule etc like this:

```py
r = mapnik.Rule()
r.symbols.append(ps)

s = mapnik.Style()
s.rules.append(r)

m.append_style('symbol_' + symbol.get_id(), s)

ds = mapnik.MemoryDatasource()
symbol_layers[symbol.get_id()] = ds

l = mapnik.Layer('%s_layer' % symbol.get_id())
l.datasource = ds
l.styles.append('symbol_' + symbol.get_id())

m.layers.append(l)
```

The actual points get added into the data source for their layer:

```py
f = mapnik.Feature.from_geojson(json.dumps({
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [float(marker.get_longitude()), float(marker.get_latitude())]
  }
}), ctx)
symbol_layers[marker.get_symbol().get_id()].add_feature(f)
```

How can I work around this? This is a major issue for me. I can't really use a visualization that hides half my data.

**Edit:** Setting `clear_label_cache` on the layer made mapnik ignore collisions from one layer to another. It's still avoiding collisions within layers, however.

**Edit2:** I was able to work around the problem by adding a separate layer and data source for each marker and using `clear_label_cache`. Not exactly elegant, but at least I get the output I need.

Comment: With `mapnik.MarkersSymbolizer()` you have name error for overlap property. It should be `ps.allow-overlap = True`. The same goes for ignore placement property and of course `mapnik.PointSymbolizer()` properties. See https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/MarkersSymbolizer and https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/PointSymbolizer

Comment: `allow-overlap` is not a legal Python identifier. If I try that I get `SyntaxError: can't assign to operator`. The Python integration actually checks the property names, so if I try misspelling it deliberately the script fails: `RuntimeError: no key found for 'allow_overlapp'`.

Comment: I admit this is not my area of expertise, I just noticed syntax in Mapnik Wiki.

Comment: Yeah, these are the official names of the properties, but they're changed when mapped into Python, in order to fit into the syntax. Thank you for trying to help, though!